# Which version of the word "dry" is suitable to question about the next step of instructions

Tags: tense, perfect-constructions

Which one of these sentence is correct?

> 1) What do we need to do after we have dry our body?
>
> 2) What do we need to do after we have dried our body?

Answer (score 1):

As @Weather Vane said in the comments:

> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we have dried our body?

You could also say:

> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we have dried our bodies?

.. if you actually mean there are multiple people.

In conversational English, you can say:

> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we have **dried off?**

The phrase “dried off” [<sup>((Definition))</sup>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dry-sb-sth-off) implies your body.

### Or you can use the present tense

And finally, if you mean in a **more general** sense, for example, if this is a repeating situation, you can use the ***present tense.***

(Notice the word “have” goes away (disappears).)

> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we dry our body?
>
> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we dry our bodies?
>
> ✔️**Yes:** What do we need to do after we dry off?